# XeLaTeX delayed output producing

Tags: xetex, texlive, windows, texworks, output

I made a few changes to my document, now it freezes for a few minutes during compilation, then continues and produces the output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Mychapter.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/footnote.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-0.mdf))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xargs/xargs.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extarrows/extarrows.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/backref.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd)
```

I found a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186824/what-could-cause-pdflatex-lualatex-to-halt-compilation-and-freeze) and the solution was unchecking the option that asks for permissions before downloading packages but it is not the case and it was already unchecked.

Comment: In some cases, it is necessary for XeTeX to create
font caches. It requires rather long time to create
the caches. In the next run, it will become faster.

Comment: It took the same amount of time after a few runs @AkiraKakuto

Comment: Have you, for example, just installed Windows 10

Comment: No, I just made a few changes to the document itself, nothing other than that @AubreyBlumsohn

Comment: @Gigili: 
(1) Create a directory if it does not exist
`$USERPROFILE/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/cache`.
(2) In a file `c:/texlive/2016/texmf.cnf`,
create a line
`FC_CACHEDIR = $TEXMFVAR/fonts/cache`.